# How to include external array inside MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In aggregation project array element from index x to y where x is defined inside collection and y is an array element corresponding to the index of the array element which is matched. Please see below example then it will become quite easier to understand what i am trying to say.

**coupons** collection

```
{"coupon_id": "coupon01", "codes": ["FLAT30", "FLAT50", "FLAT70", "FLAT90"], "curr_index": 0}
```

For example see below example code here i am trying to get coupon codes starting from curr_index to (curr_index + n) where n is the number in coupon_ctrs corresponding to the index of coupons_ids example- for id `"584559bd1f65d363bd5d25fd"` n is 1, for id `"58455a5c1f65d363bd5d2600"` n is 2 and for the id `"584878eb0005202c64b0cc5d"` n is 3.

```
coupons_ctrs = [1, 2, 3];
coupons_ids = ["584559bd1f65d363bd5d25fd", "58455a5c1f65d363bd5d2600", "584878eb0005202c64b0cc5d"];

int n = 2;
couponmodel.aggregate(
        { $match : { '_id': { $in : coupons_ids }} },
        { $project: {_id:0, codes : /* How to use slice here so that codes array will be returned between cur_index and (curr_index + coupons_ctr corresponding to the index coupon id is found, example- for _id "584559bd1f65d363bd5d25fd" it should be 1 and so on) */} },
        function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {

            } else {

            }
        });
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Styvane i could use $zip and it would work perfect but as i am using mongoDB 3.2.11 so i can't use it, so what can be the solution for using functionality of $zip in mongodb 3.2.11 ??

Can anyone please tell me how can i include this coupon_ctrs array and use it inside aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/slice) expression to each element in the "coupons_ctrs" array using the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator which means that we use the literal "coupons_ctrs" array as "input" to `$map`.

```
let coupons_ids = [
    "584559bd1f65d363bd5d25fd", 
    "58455a5c1f65d363bd5d2600", 
    "584878eb0005202c64b0cc5d"
];

let coupons_ctrs = [1, 2, 3];

db.couponmodel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match" : { "_id": { "$in" : coupons_ids } } },
        { "$project": { 
            "codes":  { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": coupons_ctrs, 
                    "as": "n", 
                    "in": { 
                        "$slice": [ 
                            "$codes", 
                            "$curr_index", 
                            { "$add": [ "$curr_index", "$$n" ] } 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

Which yields:

```
{
    "codes" : [
        [ "FLAT30" ],
        [ "FLAT30", "FLAT50" ],
        [ "FLAT30", "FLAT50",  "FLAT70" ]
    ]
}
```

In MongoDB 3.4 we can use the [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) operator to do this:

```
db.couponmodel.aggregate(     
    [ 
        { "$project": {
            "codes":  {
                "$map": {
                    "input": { 
                        "$zip": { 
                            "inputs": [ coupons_ids, coupons_ctrs ] 
                        } 
                    }, 
                    "as": "item",
                    "in": {  
                        "coupon_id": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$item", 0 ] },
                        "value": {          
                            "$slice": [  
                                "$codes",       
                                "$curr_index",    
                                { "$add": [ 
                                    "$curr_index", 
                                    { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$item", 1 ] } 
                                ] }                          
                            ]
                         }
                    }     
                } 
            } 
        }}     
    ] 
)
```

which return something like this:

```
{
    "codes" : [
        {
             "coupon_id" : "584559bd1f65d363bd5d25fd",
             "value" : [ "FLAT30" ]
        },
        {
             "coupon_id" : "58455a5c1f65d363bd5d2600",
             "value" : [ "FLAT30", "FLAT50" ],
        },
        {
             "coupon_id" : "584878eb0005202c64b0cc5d",
             "value" : [ "FLAT30", "FLAT50",  "FLAT70" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In your code where it is defined that for id: "584559bd1f65d363bd5d25fd" n will be 1, i mean is there any surety that for each id that is matching "n" will be the same index element in "coupon_ctr". ??

Comment: @PrakashKumar yes it will but you need to provide the "coupons_ids" elements index need to be in the same order as  the "coupons_ctrs" elements as you've shown.

Comment: yes it is in smae order but how can this code intenrally do that can you please explain ??

Comment: @PrakashKumar did you run the code? Is it working the way you expect?

Comment: sorry but not for first id i am getting three codes [["GETFREE"],["GETFREE"],["GETFREE"]], for second id i am getting [["FET50"],["FET50"],["FET50"]] and for third i am getting [["versace"],["versace","versace"],["versace","versace"]].

Comment: also think it this way where inside map code it is told that same index of coupon_id wiill be fetched from coupon_ctr ?? don't you think we have to do something aditional to make that happen. thanks a lot for helping me out of here i think you are just one step away from the solution.

Comment: @PrakashKumar I failed to see how you get that result. My guess is that you documents are somehow different from what you've shown here. Also I added another alternative in MongoDB 3.4. I will add explanation for both query when I have a little time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130285/discussion-between-styvane-and-prakash-kumar).

Comment: are you there @Styvane ??

Comment: Can you please see my question here both are same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090280/in-mongodb-know-index-of-array-element-matched-with-in-operator