# In mongodb know index of array element matched with $in operator?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using aggregation with mongoDB now i am facing a problem here, i am trying to match my documents which are present in my input array by using $in operator. Now i want to know the index of the lement from the input array now can anyone please tell me how can i do that.

My code

```
var coupon_ids = ["58455a5c1f65d363bd5d2600", "58455a5c1f65d363bd5d2601","58455a5c1f65d363bd5d2602"]
couponmodel.aggregate(
        { $match : { '_id': { $in : coupons_ids }} },
        /* Here i want to know index of coupon_ids element that is matched because i want to perform some operation in below code */
        function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {

            } else {

            }
        });
```

Couponmodel Schema

```
var CouponSchema = new Schema({
    category: {type: String},
    coupon_name: {type: String}, // this is a string
});
```

**UPDATE-**
As suggested by user3124885 that aggregation is not better in performance, can anyone please tell me the performance difference between aggregation and normal query in mongodb. And which one is better ??

**Update-**
I read this question on SO [mongodb-aggregation-match-vs-find-speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364319/mongodb-aggregation-match-vs-find-speed). Here the user himself commented that both take same time, also by seeing [vlad-z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245756/vlad-z) answer i think aggregation is better. Please if anyone of you have worked on mongodb Then please tell me what are your opinion about this.

**UPDATE-**
I used sample json data containing 30,000 rows and tried match with aggregation v/s find query aggregation got executed in 180 ms where find query took 220ms. ALso i ran $lookup it is also taking not much than 500ms so think aggregation is bit faster than normal query. Please correct me guys if any one of you have tried using aggregation and if not then why ??

**UPDATE-**

I read this post where user uses below code as a replacement of $zip [SERVER-20163](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20163) but i am not getting how can i solve my problem using below code. So can anybody please tell me how can i use below code to solve my issue.

```
{$map: {
    input: {
        elt1: "$array1",
        elt2: "$array2"
    },
    in: ["$elt1", "$elt2"]
}
```

Now can anyone please help me, it would be really be a great favor for me.

Comment: Why not just do a `find({_id: {$in: coupons_ids}})` and then search `coupons_ids` for the `_id` values in the returned doc(s)?

Comment: because using aggregation server overload gets reduced that's why thining about using aggregation ?? Also can you please tell me is aggregation slower or lot slower than normal query or what ?? Also i ran some cases where i have 30000 sample data and aggregation was there little bit faster than normal query.Please correct me if i am gong in wrong direction ??

Comment: What are you wanting to do within the aggregation query after matching the elements?

Comment: @KevinSmith i want to return coupon_ctr at same index as in coupon_id which is matched

Comment: Have you got an example of the structure of the documents inside `couponmodel` collection

Comment: let me add schema of couponmodel

Comment: you can have a relook but it has nothing to do with it because i only want to match _id of documents inside couponsmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So say we have the following in the database collection:

```
> db.couponmodel.find()
{ "_id" : "a" }
{ "_id" : "b" }
{ "_id" : "c" }
{ "_id" : "d" }
```

and we wish to search for the following ids in the collections

```
var coupons_ids = ["c", "a" ,"z"];
```

We'll then have to build up a dynamic projection state so that we can project the correct indexes, so we'll have to map each id to its corresponding index

```
var conditions = coupons_ids.map(function(value, index){
    return { $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$_id', value] }, then: index, else: -1 } };
});
```

Then we can then inject this in to our aggregation pipeline

```
db.couponmodel.aggregate([
    { $match : { '_id' : { $in : coupons_ids } } },
    { $project: { indexes : conditions } },
    { $project: {
        index : {
            $filter: { 
                input: "$indexes", as: "indexes", cond: { $ne: [ "$$indexes", -1 ] }
                }
            }
        } 
    },
    { $unwind: '$index' }
]);
```

Running the above will now output each _id and it's corresponding index within the `coupons_ids` array

```
{ "_id" : "a", "index" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "c", "index" : 0 }
```

However we can also add more items in to the pipeline at the end and reference `$index` to get the current matched index.

Comment: sorry but you misunderstood my question i want coupon_ctr value to return along with _id.

Comment: You're question has nothing related to `coupon_ctr` within it, can you explain in more details?

Comment: I am so sorry but let me explain, actually your are printing index from database but i want index according to coupon_ids which is internal array which i am passing so output should be this { "_id" : "a", "index" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "c", "index" : 0 }

Comment: That is the index from the array... we've just injected in some projections so we can work out the correct location in the array... If you look at my output it is the same as what you describe

Comment: bro thanks let me try your code but in the mean time can please read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121490/mongodb-aggregation-v-s-simple-query-performance

Comment: can you please explain what this coupons_ids.map is doing ??

Comment: It's creating the conditions for each match to return the index so it can be placed in the projection :-)

Comment: thanks alot man it is working completely as expected :) you are a life saviour bro

Comment: also one more thing how can i use update in aggregation ??

Comment: Aggregation is only to getting data, you can however push to a new collection using $out

Comment: can you please have a look at my next question i think yu can help me out, it is the same question as this one but i have to perform this on update. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142265/update-in-mongodb-with-in-query

Comment: got anything brother ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it in a faster way simply retrieving the array and search manually. Remember that aggregation don't give you performance.

Comment: yes but computation on server makes server busy which is also a major problem, that's why trying to use aggregation. Please enlighten me if you think i am thinking it in wrong direction.

Comment: also is agregation much slower than normal query, because i have seen it on SO questions then they both take same time to run a query, please coorect me if am wrong ?? also thanks for posting an answer here.

Comment: No aggregation is the lowest operation in MongoDB instead of the other operations. In your case, if you haven't other operations to do in the aggregation, I advertise you simply to :

Comment: also aggreagtion is not lowest as map reduce is multiple time sslower than aggregation.

Comment: I saw your updated post. MongoDB is a NOSQL database, so you have to create the database structure in non-relational way.

Comment: So, you must prefer embedded documents instead of collection relationship. Aggregation is not good in MongoDB. It is useful in certain occasions, but it must be avoided, in particular way when you have collection with much data.

Comment: how can you surely say that ?? i mean where is it written ?? can you show me any source ??

Comment: If you think well, why do you prefer MongoDB instead of a classic SQL? MongoDB is faster in write operations, but slower in read operations. MongoDB provide you the dynamic model design. Aggregation exist, but go against with the MongoDB embedded principle.

Comment: sorry but on the link i did not find anything about aggregation not being recommended in front of simple query ?? where is it written ??

Comment: I am so sorry can you please  explain this deeply. What do you mean by embedded principle and how aggregation support it and simple query doesn't ??

Comment: @Prakash Aggregation must be avoided according to the case. Your case is "aggregating" 30.000 rows. This is not acceptable. You can do it if you want, but allow disk usage and prepare to scale your server application. Find() is faster than an Aggregate().

Comment: but why when i ran aggrgation on my sample it was fast than find() ?? because find took 220 ms and aggregate 180 ms ?? please help me ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130437/discussion-between-prakash-kumar-and-andreas-limoli).

Comment: hey i have asked a seperate question on this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121490/mongodb-aggregation-v-s-simple-query-performance please help.

Comment: As I wrote in chat, aggregation causes recursions. You can end it before respect of the normal find if there are few data. Moreover in my opinion aggregation goes against the nosql principle.

Answer (score 0):

//$match,$in,$and

```
    $match:{
        $and:[        
        {"uniqueID":{$in:["CONV0001"]}},
        {"parentID":{$in:["null"]}},
        ]
       }
   }])
```

Comment: @devpato There is no link in the answer